# Can't attach the sample database in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I have downloaded the sample database for SQL Server 2012 Express but I am having the following error message whenever I try to attach it:

> The database 'AdventureWorks2012' cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the server you are trying to attach the database to is not SQL Server 2012. This may be the version of Management Studio / Management Studio Express you're using, but I suspect `SELECT @@VERSION;` will tell you something different. It may just be a connection string mixup if you have multiple instances of SQL Server installed, otherwise you should [download and install SQL Server 2012 Express from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062).

Comment: I am sure that both of them are for the SQL Server 2012 edition. But I believe that there is a bug with the application.

Comment: @darking050 I am sure you are sure, but please show us what `SELECT @@VERSION;` says.

Comment: it is shown Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64) 
 Mar 29 2009 10:11:52 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 8400: ). But I am sure it is SQL Server 2012 from the about menu????

Comment: The About Menu is talking about ***Management Studio***. Your server is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: So what I have is 2012 Management Studio with 2008 Server Database?