# Error: Can't attach DB to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2012 and I'm trying to attach a db which was previously used with SQL Server 2012, surprisingly I'm getting the following error:

> The database 'DatabaseName' cannot be opened because it is version
>   706. This server supports version 622 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

I don't really understand how this could happen since like I said it was used with same 2012 version. What am I doing wrong? How can I make it work? Please explain in detail how this can be resolved.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error sounds like the server you are trying to attach the database to is not SQL Server 2012. This may be the version of Management Studio / Management Studio Express you're using, but I suspect `SELECT @@VERSION;` will tell you something different. It may just be a connection string mixup if you have multiple instances of SQL Server installed, otherwise you should [download and install SQL Server 2012 Express from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062).

[@source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569882/cant-attach-the-sample-database-in-sql-server-2012)

Comment: SELECT @@VERSION GIVES: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64) ....... That doesn't make any sense since Help->About gives me SQL Server 2012 logo info with a row saying: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60.... Confusing :o Any idea?

Comment: It means that your server is SQL Server 2008

Comment: It amy be that you have 2012 Management Studio with 2008 Server Database. That is why this error occurred.

Comment: Okay ive just checked my installed programs, considering the fact i formatted my pc yesterday and didnt install SQL2008 directly (WIRED!), i do see there a list of sql server 2008 components and the program itself, could u please advice if i should remove them all or just the SQL2008 ?

Comment: You can remove it and install a fresh software from the link in the question. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Updating: Worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you had the following configuration and source databases:

1. SQL Server 2008 SP3 (ver 10.0...) - database engine
2. SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (ver 11.0...) - management tools
3. a database that was created with SQL Server 2012 (version 706)

As mentioned you could install SSMS for SQL Server 2008 (after you uninstall SSMS for SQL Server 2012).  Then you would have to script your database for that version and re-run the script via 'Tasks>Script...', remembering to set the target server version as shown below.

[image: Script for Server Version option]

After scripting you can then use the import/export wizard to export and then inport the data into the new (downgraded database), assuming the database had no 2012-only datatypes (such as sequences).

Another consideration is database compatibility level as shown below.  You can have a SQL Server 2012 instance which hosts databases with various compatibility levels.

[image: Database compatibility level]

Answer (score 0):

Using `SELECT @@VERSION` works very well for me. Your Database Engine is connected to a 2008 DB which certainly doesn't allow you to attach. Once I change my Database Engine to connect to 2012 DB, it works for me.

Check your Database Engine connection. You can be working on 2012 Management Studio yet connecting to 2008 DB. This is what happened to me and I have solved it use SELECT @@VERSION.